# How to create Mongo DB collections using Azure Bicep script

Tags: azure, arm

I have prepared a script which will create the collection for Mongo DB API using bicep script, but i am unable to add the keys and other values which i have defined in the collections array.

Help me out to create the collection with all the name and the keys defined in the variable collection as below:

**CODE**

```
// Containers
param db_collections array = [
  {
    name       : 'companies'
    throughput : 400
    autoscale_settings : []
  }
  {
    name       : 'countries'
    indexes : [
      {
        keys   : ['_id']
        unique : true
      }
      {
        keys   : ['active', 'name']
        unique : false
      }
      {
        keys   : ['active']
        unique : false
      }
      {
        keys   : ['name']
        unique : false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```